# How I can add endpoint actuator/metrics to my Java project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator

I implemented the:
`implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.0.1")`

dependency,
and added:
`management: endpoints: web: exposure: include: "*"`

to `application.yml`,
when I send requests to `POSTMAN`:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/...

all required endpoints are available except metrics

How I can add this?

I tried to add:

```
@Autowired
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    @Bean
    public CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar() {
        return new CacheMetricsRegistrar(meterRegistry, Lists.newArrayList(new CaffeineCacheMeterBinderProvider()));
    }
```

but I got an error > Process `'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin/java.exe''` finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable it via yaml/properties?

```
management.defaults.metrics.export.enabled=true
```

```yaml
management:
  defaults:
    metrics:
      export:
        enabled: true
```

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics